# SSRS Scope with Row and Column groups issues

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm trying to get percentage calculated for my tablix and have problem on very last column, which is outside of Column Group, can't make it work, I can't use  `Dataset` as I have a filter on tablix level.  Pic below illustrates all my setup.  I Understand if you stay inside the box then you have all right scopes, curious if I can do any right click and see what scope is ??) 
I need somehow to get value =1837 to use in pink boxes.

I  tried to digest error message and tried all combo but not helps

Is this doable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you not just add a column group for the year and repeat all you expressions as you have with month and quarter.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to your very last column which is outside the groups and the deatils with the following expression. Lets say your `Total` from `YTD` is in **Textbox1**. Then you can refer to this textbox (because its outside the detail rows):

```
=ReportItems!Textbox1.Value   'Result: 1837
```

But a better way to calculate the percentage in the pink boxes would be the following expression (this expression comes in the pink box):

```
=Sum(Fields!YTDDetail.Value, "TurnDays") / Sum(Fields!YTDDetail.Value, "Dataset")
```

This way you are dividing the grouped sum with the whole sum, which should result in your percentage if you format the output of the texbox as **Number > Percentage**.

Comment: Tx S!!!  I go with ReportItems,  I have filter on tablix so Dataset scope doesn't work for me. Best.M